# NodeJS passport authentication fail right after loging in

Tags: node.js, passport-local

I'm facing an issue with the **passport-local-mongoose** module. I had a classic authentication routine with a login and register page, and an home page redirection after successfuly entered their credentials.
Basicaly, it happen between this two function :

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

// some code

router.get('/:pagename', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            var pageName = req.params.pagename;
            var data = pageFiller[pageName].getInitialState();

            res.render(pageName, data);
        });
    })(req, res, next)
});
```

I see in my browser console the following redirection **after having loged myself** :

1. /somepage, *not authenticated => redirect to login page*
2. /login, *successfuly entered credentials => redirect to home page*
3. /home, *instant redirection to login page*
4. /login.

Some tests I already made :

- In the 2 step callback function I have printed the user, to ensure its existence. It was OK.
- I tried to access /home directly by entering the url in the browser.

Thanks to you in advance.

login > /home > /login.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad... I'm very very new to this.

I was inducted in error by simple exemples I rode and **used the authentication as verification in every other routes**.
[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619) (Protecting route section) is a easy-to-understand implementation.